# Javafx canvas not clearing correctly.

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, boids

I've written a java implementation of Craig Reynolds Boids. I recently updated each object to be represented by a .png image. Ever since I've been having the display issue in the image.

What's the best way to fix the issue?

- I've tried using a Polygon but when one of my coordinates is a negative the triangle doesn't display properly.

[image: Boids]

Main Class:

```
public void paint(final GraphicsContext g) {
    new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            flock.updateBoidsPostion();
            g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            flock.drawBoids(g);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Boids Flocking Algorithm");
    Group root = new Group();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

    paint(gc);

}
```

Flock:

```
/**
 * Paint each boid comprising the flock the canvas.
 * @param g
 */
public void drawBoids(GraphicsContext g) {
    for(Boid aBoid : boids) {
        aBoid.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Boid:

```
public void draw(GraphicsContext g) {
    //coordinates for the tip of the boid
    int x = (int)this.position.xPos;
    int y = (int)this.position.yPos;

    //Calculate a angle representing the direction of travel. 
    Rotate r = new Rotate(angle, x, y);
    g.setTransform(r.getMxx(), r.getMyx(), r.getMxy(), r.getMyy(), r.getTx(), r.getTy());

    g.drawImage(image, x, y);   
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use JavaFX nodes? And could you please share your code? I've recently heard about the Boids and I'm curious how that works. Regarding your question my first guess is that the problem is that you are transforming the GraphicsContext, not the image, not transforming the GC back, etc. But that's just a guess, hard to say without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I could use a ImageView node, I hadn't thought of that. The rest of the code related to determining the position of the boid inside the canvas rather than display. The whole thing is based on [this](http://www.kfish.org/boids/pseudocode.html)

Comment: I'd definitely go with ImageViews. Then it's also easier to exchange the ImageView nodes by different objects, e. g. shapes. Thanks, I know that paper. I'm more curious about it being implemented in JavaFX. Don't have the time to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you rotate the GraphicsContext, not the image. Or at least you don't rotate the GraphicsContext back after you rotated it.

---

I was curious about the link you mentioned, i. e. the [Boids Pseudocode](http://www.kfish.org/boids/pseudocode.html).

Here's a quick implementation. Drag the rectangle to have the flock follow it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// Boids implementation in JavaFX
// Pseudo code by Conrad Parker: http://www.kfish.org/boids/pseudocode.html
public class Main extends Application {

    int numBoids = 50;
    double boidRadius = 10d;
    double boidMinDistance = boidRadius * 2d + 5; // +5 = arbitrary value
    double initialBaseVelocity = 1d;
    double velocityLimit = 3d;
    double movementToCenter = 0.01; // 1% towards center

    List<Boid> boids;

    static Random rnd = new Random();

    double sceneWidth = 1024;
    double sceneHeight = 768;

    Pane playfield;

    Rectangle rectangle;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        playfield = new Pane();
        playfield.setPrefSize(sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        Text infoText = new Text( "Drag the rectangle and have the flock follow it");
        root.setTop(infoText);

        root.setCenter(playfield);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight, Color.WHITE);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // create boids
        createBoids();

        // add boids to scene
        playfield.getChildren().addAll(boids);

        double w = 20;
        double h = 20;
        rectangle = new Rectangle( w, h);
        rectangle.relocate(sceneWidth / 2 - w/2, sceneHeight / 4 - h/2);
        playfield.getChildren().add(rectangle);

        MouseGestures mg = new MouseGestures();
        mg.makeDraggable(rectangle);

        // animation loop
        AnimationTimer loop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                boids.forEach(Boid::move);
                boids.forEach(Boid::updateUI);

            }
        };

        loop.start();
    }

    private void createBoids() {

        boids = new ArrayList<>();

        // margin from top/left/bottom/right, so we have the boids initially more in the center
        double marginX = sceneWidth / 4;
        double marginY = sceneHeight / 4;

        for (int i = 0; i < numBoids; i++) {

            // random position around the center
            double x = rnd.nextDouble() * (sceneWidth - marginX * 2) + marginX;
            double y = rnd.nextDouble() * (sceneHeight - marginY * 2) + marginY;

            // initial random velocity depending on speed
            double v = Math.random() * 4 + initialBaseVelocity;

            Boid boid = new Boid(i, x, y, v);

            boids.add(boid);

        }

    }


    // Rule 1: Boids try to fly towards the centre of mass of neighbouring boids. 
    public Point2D rule1(Boid boid) {

        Point2D pcj = new Point2D(0, 0);

        for( Boid neighbor: boids)  {

            if( boid == neighbor)
                continue;

            pcj = pcj.add( neighbor.position);

        }

        if( boids.size() > 1) {
            double div = 1d / (boids.size() - 1);
            pcj = pcj.multiply( div);
        }

        pcj = (pcj.subtract(boid.position)).multiply( movementToCenter);

        return pcj;
    }

    // Rule 2: Boids try to keep a small distance away from other objects (including other boids). 
    public Point2D rule2(Boid boid) {

        Point2D c = new Point2D(0, 0);

        for( Boid neighbor: boids)  {

            if( boid == neighbor)
                continue;

            double distance = (neighbor.position.subtract(boid.position)).magnitude();

            if( distance < boidMinDistance) {
                c = c.subtract(neighbor.position.subtract(boid.position));
            }

        }

        return c;
    }

    // Rule 3: Boids try to match velocity with near boids. 
    public Point2D rule3(Boid boid) {

        Point2D pvj = new Point2D(0, 0);

        for( Boid neighbor: boids)  {

            if( boid == neighbor)
                continue;

            pvj = pvj.add( neighbor.velocity);

        }

        if( boids.size() > 1) {
            double div = 1d / (boids.size() - 1);
            pvj = pvj.multiply( div);
        }

        pvj = (pvj.subtract(boid.velocity)).multiply(0.125); // 0.125 = 1/8

        return pvj;
    }


    // tend towards the rectangle
    public Point2D tendToPlace( Boid boid) {

        Point2D place = new Point2D( rectangle.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + rectangle.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2, rectangle.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() + rectangle.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2);

        return (place.subtract(boid.position)).multiply( 0.01);
    }

    public class Boid extends Circle {

        int id;

        Point2D position;
        Point2D velocity;

        double v;

        // random color
        Color color = randomColor();

        public Boid(int id, double x, double y, double v) {

            this.id = id;
            this.v = v;

            position = new Point2D( x, y);
            velocity = new Point2D( v, v);

            setRadius( boidRadius);

            setStroke(color);
            setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.2));

        }

        public void move() {

            Point2D v1 = rule1(this);
            Point2D v2 = rule2(this);
            Point2D v3 = rule3(this);
            Point2D v4 = tendToPlace(this);

            velocity = velocity
                    .add(v1)
                    .add(v2)
                    .add(v3)
                    .add(v4)
                    ;

            limitVelocity();

            position = position.add(velocity);

            constrainPosition();
        }

        private void limitVelocity() {

            double vlim = velocityLimit;

            if( velocity.magnitude() > vlim) {
                 velocity = (velocity.multiply(1d/velocity.magnitude())).multiply( vlim);
            }

        }


        // limit position to screen dimensions
        public void constrainPosition() {

            double xMin = boidRadius;
            double xMax = sceneWidth - boidRadius;
            double yMin = boidRadius;
            double yMax = sceneHeight - boidRadius;

            double x = position.getX();
            double y = position.getY();
            double vx = velocity.getX();
            double vy = velocity.getY();

            if( x < xMin) {
                x = xMin;
                vx = v;
            }
            else if( x > xMax) {
                x = xMax;
                vx = -v;
            }

            if( y < yMin) {
                y = yMin;
                vy = v;
            }
            else if( y > yMax) {
                y = yMax;
                vy = -v;
            }

            // TODO: modification would be less performance consuming => find out how to modify the vector directly or create own Poin2D class
            position = new Point2D( x, y);
            velocity = new Point2D( vx, vy);

        }


        public void updateUI() {

            setCenterX(position.getX());
            setCenterY(position.getY());
        }
    }


    public static Color randomColor() {
        int range = 220;
        return Color.rgb((int) (rnd.nextDouble() * range), (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * range), (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * range));
    }


    public static class MouseGestures {

        class DragContext {
            double x;
            double y;
        }

        DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        public void makeDraggable( Node node) {
            node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseDragged( onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseReleased( onMouseReleasedEventHandler);
        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                if( event.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                    Circle circle = ((Circle) (event.getSource()));

                    dragContext.x = circle.getCenterX() - event.getSceneX();
                    dragContext.y = circle.getCenterY() - event.getSceneY();

                } else {

                    Node node = ((Node) (event.getSource()));

                    dragContext.x = node.getTranslateX() - event.getSceneX();
                    dragContext.y = node.getTranslateY() - event.getSceneY();

                }
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                if( event.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                    Circle circle = ((Circle) (event.getSource()));

                    circle.setCenterX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                    circle.setCenterY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());

                } else {

                    Node node = ((Node) (event.getSource()));

                    node.setTranslateX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                    node.setTranslateY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());

                }

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            }
        };

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

A 3D version is just a matter of using Points3D instead of Points2D and Spheres and Boxes instead of Circles and Rectangles.

[image]

I also suggest you read the excellent book [The Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/introduction/) by Daniel Shiffman, especially the chapter [Autonomous Agents](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/). It deals in detail with the Boids.

Comment: I like the use of a attraction point you can drag around the screen. I''ve updated mine to use a ImageView nodes rather than a canvas and it's working well. Out of curiosity, how well does your implementation meet rule 2? Dealing with collision avoidance.

Comment: You can try it yourself, it's the full source code. Just put it into a javafx class and start it. Regarding rule 2: I did it as mentioned in the pseudo code. But when they are all very close, they move too quickly. Looks like they are vibrating, i. e. they are not smooth. They seem to need some kind of damping function. It all depends on the speed you set.

Comment: Just curious. I had the same problem. By introducing a movement factor like rule 1, I could stop the 'bouncing' around. By it does result in some overlap in certain situations like when the flock approaches the corners of the screen.

Comment: @DavidFinder: I stumbled upon The Nature of Code which is excellent for understanding how the boids work. The code examples are in Processing, but that's very easy to convert to JavaFX.